# Encountering tagName.toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to automate a web application built on *Angular* on the front-end.
I have a form where I need to click a button.

**HTML code:**
[image]

**JavaScript code to click:**

```
cy.get('.modal-body.container .ng-star-inserted a.ng-star-inserted').click()
```

**Error in *Cypress runner*:**
[image]

I do not understand why I see the `tagName.toLowerCase()` function while executing a click on the *ADD BUTTON* of the form page. I have not defined this function in the code anywhere.

Comment: Instead of having a long chain of selectors, try to give the `a` tag a class and then do `cy.get('.modal-body.container  .<YOUR-CLASS-NAME>').click()`. It will be easy to debug.

Comment: Hi Vighnesh, I used cy.get('.modal-body.container .ng-star-inserted a.ng-star-inserted').click() , I still get the same error. Please Can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

Opened an issue https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/8191 and seems like it is a bug on Cypress side. However I found a workaround by using the .then() function. Code below :

```
 cy.get('.modal-body.container .ng-star-inserted a.ng-star-inserted').then(($el) => {
    console.log($el)
}).find('.mat-icon').then(($ol) => {
    $ol.click()
})
```